# doctrine 2 where condition without comparison

Tags: oracle, doctrine-orm, dql

I have written a custom function for the DQL:

```
 <?php namespace Bundle\DQL\Functions;

 use Doctrine\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\FunctionNode;
 use Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer;
 use Doctrine\ORM\Query\SqlWalker;
 use Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser;

 /**
  * "DATE_COMPARE" "(" ArithmeticPrimary "," ComparisonOperator "," ArithmeticPrimary ")"
  */
 class DateCompareFunction extends FunctionNode
 {
     public $date1;
     public $date2;
     public $operator;

    /**
      * @override
     * @param SqlWalker $sqlWalker
     * @return string
     * @throws \Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException
     */
     public function getSql(SqlWalker $sqlWalker)
     {
        return sprintf(
            'TRUNC(%s) %s TRUNC(%s)',
            $this->date1->dispatch($sqlWalker),
            $this->operator,
            $this->date2->dispatch($sqlWalker)
        );
     }

     /**
      * @override
     * @param Parser $parser
      */
     public function parse(Parser $parser)
     {
         $parser->match(Lexer::T_IDENTIFIER);
         $parser->match(Lexer::T_OPEN_PARENTHESIS);
         $this->date1 = $parser->ArithmeticPrimary();
         $parser->match(Lexer::T_COMMA);
         $this->operator = $parser->ComparisonOperator();
         $parser->match(Lexer::T_COMMA);
         $this->date2 = $parser->ArithmeticPrimary();
         $parser->match(Lexer::T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS);
     }
 }
```

And my where stmt looks like this:

```
$query = $em->createQueryBuilder()
            ->select('evt')
            ->from('Application\Model\Event', 'evt')
            ->where('evt.USR_ID in (:uid)')
            ->setParameter('uid', $usersId);

        if (null !== $from) {
            $query->andWhere('DATE_COMPARE(evt.DAY, >, TO_DATE(:from, \'yyyy-mm-dd\'))')
                ->setParameter('from', $from);
```

The problem is that Doctrine raise an exception for having a `WHERE` statement without comparison symbol:

```
object(Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException)[347]
  protected 'message' => string '[Syntax Error] line 0, col 130: Error: Expected =, <, <=, <>, >, >=, !=, got ')'' (length=80)
  private 'string' (Exception) => string '' (length=0)
  protected 'code' => int 0
  protected 'file' => string 'C:\Workspace\app\hcalendar\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException.php' (length=88)
  protected 'line' => int 52
  private 'trace' (Exception) =>
```

I have tried adding a `stmt = TRUE`, but the generated statement isn't understood by oracle, hwo can I do a where statement without any comparison symbol ? (just a true/false function return)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you need this function? you can do the where condition without custom function, just write:

```
$query->andWhere('evt.day > :from')->setParameter('from', $from);
```

where the variable `$from` should be a DateTime object, and if you want the Oracle `TRUNC` function you can implement it by it self as in here https://github.com/ZeinEddin/ZeDoctrineExtensions/blob/master/lib/ZeDoctrineExtensions/Query/Oracle/TruncDate.php and just use it like this:

```
$query->andWhere('trunc(evt.day) > :from')->setParameter('from', $from);
```

If you want you can install [this module](https://github.com/ZeinEddin/ZeZfDoctrineExtensions) for a ZF2 project and you will have the `TruncDate` function ready to be used in your project

Comment: That's the solution I had implemented :)