# Doctrine 2 reports error when consulting date with Oracle 12c

Tags: php, oracle, doctrine-orm

I'm working with an Oracle Database and I'm trying to make a consult between dates. The date fields are varchar type because I can't make it date. So, when I try to make a consult between two dates I've got the next error:

> [Syntax Error] line 0, col 51: Error: Expected known function, got 'to_date'

The query is ...

```
$query = $em->createQuery("SELECT es.* FROM Privado\Entity\APPaiEntity es WHERE to_date(es.datePlan, 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') >= to_date('" . $fromDate . "', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')");
```

Maybe, the correct solution is to work with DateTime type fields, so ... How can I work with DateTime type fields in Doctrine 2 with Oracle 12c?

Comment: Check out this question, you'll likely need to register to_date with doctrine  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25883616/how-can-i-use-date-in-doctrine-2-dql

Comment: Thank you but I'm working with Zend Framework 2 and not with Symphony. I think, I need a guide to do what I need to "to_date".

Comment: From your question, Doctrine is the library you're using.  This can be used in both Zend and Symphony.  The Doctrine documentation linked from that ticket should be relevant regardless of the PHP framework you are using.  Additionally, you may find that you don't need to_date at all.  The accepted answer to this question <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26275812/doctrine-2-where-condition-without-comparison> shows how to do basic date comparison.

Comment: Thank you for your help but I' still don't knowing how to solve my problem. Is there any place with any example, please?